# Place created DLL and import library in separate directories

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, build-process

I have a VC++ Win32 DLL project. I wonder if anyone can help me to force the linker to put the DLL in one directory and the import library (LIB file) into another directory?
Any help is appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In project properties /Linker/General/Output File is path and name of dll. Linker/Advanced/Import Library is path and name of the lib.

(That's for VS2003, similar or same for other versions)

Comment: Thanks! The MSDN docs make it sound like it's just a file name, not a path. I should've just tried that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In your project settings, set the post condition to where you want your dll and lib copied to.